# 301 Redirect directory to it's included file

Tags: .htaccess, file, redirect, directory

I have **bali** **directory** in root folder. It contains **main_bali.php** and other many php file . I want to redirect

```
http://domain.com/bali/
```

to

```
http://domain.com/bali/main_bali.php
```

I use

```
Redirect 301 bali/ bali/main_bali.php
```

and many other tricks. but none of them works. when entering domain.com/bali in url it display domain.com/bali/main_bali.php but display internal error. I search and use htaccess folder to file redirect syntax. But I cannot customize according to my case. What can I do in this case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `RedirectMatch` for precise matching using regex:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(bali)/?$ /$1/main_bali.php
```

Comment: Thanks for response, but it still display message. ERROR 500 - INTERNAL SERVER ERROR.

Comment: means ??? I can't understand. RedirectMatch 301 ^/(bali)/?$ /$1/main_bali.php doesn't work it says ERROR 500 - INTERNAL SERVER ERROR.

Comment: Exact same rule worked for me. Make sure you don't have .htaccess in `/bali/` and there is no other rule in root .htaccess except this one while testing.

Comment: Thanks so much. I create .htaccess file under bali directory and edit according you, it works. Thanks for your time!